# Selenium Headless Chrome React onMouseEnter

Tags: reactjs, selenium, google-chrome, headless

I have a weird problem. For my testing I am trying to run selenium with a headless chrome version. I use nightwatch to test my javascript React application.

One of my components uses the onMouseEnter event to display a submenu, but when I use nightwatch's moveToElement method it works with normal chrome but not with headless chrome. It gives me no error but the submenu is simply not shown.

This is my nightwatch test:

```
browser
      // Load the page at the launch URL
      .url(browser.launchUrl).useXpath()
      // wait for page to load
      .waitForElementVisible("//ul/li/div/span[text()='Login']", 5000)
      //hover over Login
      .moveToElement("//ul/li/div/span[text()='Login']", 10, 10)
      //wait for submenu
      .waitForElementVisible("//ul/li/ul/li/a/span[text()='Login']", 500)
```

When I run it with normal chrome it successfully finishes the test, but with chrome --headless I get the following error:

```
- open login modal (5.22s)
Timed out while waiting for element <//ul/li/ul/li/a/span[text()='Login']> to be present for 500 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
   at Object.open login modal
   at process._tickCallback
```

I am quite not sure why this happens in headless mode and how I can prevent that.

Edit: I fixed now my problem by updating my react menu component (rc-menu v5 => v7) and now it works also in headless mode, although I still don't know why it didn't work before...

Comment: Your are moving to 10,10 position. check the window size in headless mode? is it same? check with screen shot?

Comment: I already thought about that, I took a screenshot and the component with the hover function has an approximate size of 68x50. I run chrome --headless with --window-size=1920,1080.